# Can't bind to remote service

Tags: android

after calling:

```
result=bindService(new Intent(IUdpListenerService.class.getName()),
            serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

byt debugger: result return 'true'

the onServiceConnected isn't being called.

*ill mention that the remote service is installed in diffrent apk, and is being started by the command startService(..)

Okie.. this is new thing i just found out: onServiceConnected is being triggerd, but it takes time, so what happens here.. that when i use the instance of my interface -  it's still remine null, before onServiceConnected manage to be triggerd.. is that possible? –

Comment: why are you adding getName() after class?

Comment: honestly.. i dont know.. i took it from an example. how would u adjust it?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse and look for warnings. You will usually get a warning if Android could not identify your service to bind to it, for example.

Comment: And if that's my example, you would need to have adjusted your service's `<intent-filter>` to match.

Comment: I did use.. nothing being shown after the bindService(..) being called.. and the instance of the interface, ofcourse remine null coz onServiceConnected hasnt being called.. i watch it by the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service needs to have an `<intent-filter>` with an action:

```
    <service android:name=".BshService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.commonsware.android.advservice.IScript" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

You can then use the action form of an `Intent` to bind to it:

```
new Intent("com.commonsware.android.advservice.IScript")
```

or, if your client happens to have a class or interface named `IScript` in the `com.commonsware.android.advservice` package:

```
new Intent(IScript.getName());
```

Comment: if result return true (plz check my edit), isnt it a sign that the binded success?

Comment: Okie.. this is new thing i just found out: now onServiceConnected is being triggerd, but it takes time, so what happens here.. that the instance of my interface - when i use it, it's still remine null, before onServiceConnected manage to be trigger.. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the ServiceConnection is null until onServiceConnected is called (as its name suggests).

Comment: yes.. but this operation creates sync? coz after bindservice i have operation which uses IUdpListenerService.. and it seems that it still null, ever after bindservice return TRUE

Comment: `bindService()` is asynchronous. You cannot do the "operation which uses IUdpListenerService" until `onServiceConnected()` is called.

Comment: Ohh thanks for this POINT!! you are great.. i am getting crazy here.. but please is there any standart way to solve this some how? like how will i make my operation wait for onServiceConnected() to be called?(without UI touch)

Comment: "like how will i make my operation wait for onServiceConnected() to be called?" You move the code into `onServiceConnected()`. For example, you don't have a `Thread.sleep()` call in `onCreate()` waiting for somebody to click a button -- you put the code that needs to wait for a button-click into the `onClick()` method you assign to the button. Similarly, you don't wait in `onCreate()` for a bound connection -- you put the code that needs to wait for a bound connection into the `onServiceConnected()` method.

Comment: Thanks.!  
Are you giving phone consults? I asked my team leader for consulting hours.. and suggested about u.

Comment: Click on my name to view my profile page, which has a link to my Web site, where you can learn more.

Answer (score 1):

The `Intent` constructor you use takes an `Action`, not a class name. To start a certain service, use `new Intent(<package context, e.g. this>, IUdpListenerService.class)` instead.

**Update:** to start a Service or Activity in another package, use setComponent:

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.remote", "com.remote.IUdpListenerService"));
```

(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application) question for details)

Comment: If my remote service is in another application called remote, and under the package called com.remote, how would u adjust it? coz i tried it , and it also didnt work

Comment: You want to start a service in another package? See the answer for this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application