# Unable to fire an intent to applications

Tags: android

How to fire an intent from an activity to inbuilt applications in android? Am writing an application where i can set a shortcut key to the applications. Am able to save the key and other things. but how to launch that application from this activity? How to Fire an intent to inbuilt apps in android like Calculator, messaging etc..

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question was asked a while ago.

[How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

there is an answer to your problem

Comment: Thank you will get back to you if i face any problem implementing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can bring calculator infront.see 
[here](http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/08/starting-android-calculator.html)

Comment: Thank you will get back to you if i face any problem implementing it!