# Is there anyway to directly start one of your activy?

Tags: java, android, android-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start activity in another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application)

My application schema is like that ;

```
SplashActivty ( <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> )
LoginActivity 
MainActivty 
    BanksActivity ( Gridview  of some banks ) 
      BankActivity ( Some detail information  about selected bank )
          Request loan 
          etc.
    HotelsActivty ( Gridview of some hotels ) 
          HotelActivty 
          etc. ( same hierarcy as banks...)
```

Additional info: All activities/actions  makes request an api call for retrieving informations and assets of  that screen.

My scenario/question is that;

Is there anyway; can I start BanksActivty or one of other activity which is not launcher nor mainActivity directly from outside of my app ?

Does the question makes sense?

Comment: From where would it be launched? Notification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you want to start it from home screen, just add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` (and remove the original line there for this activity):

```
    <activity android:name="MyHotelActivity"
              android:label="MyHotelActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And your `MyHotelActivity` will have an icon in installed programs.

You can also start it in response to any other ´intent-filter` type that you may want to register.

Regards.