# Launch application by calling a number

Tags: android

I am an android developer. (beginner)

And I want to know how can I make my application launch by entering/calling a specific code number (from the same device), such as smart lock application, you can launch it by calling this code #000.

Answer (score 3):

**You have to use Broadcast Receiver...**

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
            Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            if(code.equals("#000") {
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
```

**And Your Android Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.varma.samples.detectcalls.receivers.OutgoingCallReceiver"> 
                    <intent-filter> 
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                    </intent-filter> 
            </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch application by it's full package name [How to start activity in another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application). You can implement desired logic inside your app-launcher. like bind a code #000 to a specific package like "com.example.android".

```
if(code.equals("#000") {
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
}
else if{code.equals(#???"){
     //another app
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you well, but how can I bind a code to a specific package. I mean I couldn't understand you! Thank you.

Comment: It seems that I didn't explain my question very well. I meant that I want to launch my application when somebody trying to call a specific code number from Phone application. Hopefully It's clear now, and thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @user1843769 I think it's impossible.

Comment: It isn't impossible and I found a way to do that. Thank you for your trying to help me.

Comment: @user1843769 can you share with your investigations?