# How to find out the reason why Activity doesn't start

Tags: android, android-activity

I got log cat message from `startAnotherActivity()` method

```
private void startAnotherActivity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startAnotherActivity()");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(ANOTHER_ACTIVITY);
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Another activity doesn't start, no other messages in log cat.**

How can I resolve this issue?

UPDATE#1:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that AnotherActivity is an Activity in the other application, and therefore `ANOTHER_ACTIVITY == 'some.other.app.domain.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY'`

Shouldn't Dalvik complain if it cannot find specified activity?

Comment: Show us how you declare the `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: if no activity is found for that action/category, an exception is raised. there has to be something in the logcat

Comment: `Entered startAnotherActivity()` do you see this in your `LogCat`?

Comment: @Blundell 
Yes, I do

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason may be not declaring other activity in the manifest. You can do this like the following:

```
    <activity android:name="your.package.your.activity">
    </activity>
```

And then you can start the activity by doing the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it can't help 'cause I need to launch an activity from another app

Comment: @zuba maybe this link may help then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an activity in another application, you may need to set the component (fully qualified package name and fully qualified activity name). 
See here: [How to start activity in another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application)

Or here:
[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Looking promising, Thank you!
I'll try that right now

Comment: Just have tried, but it ended up with the same result

Comment: Did you try both approaches? (there were 2 links). Did you get an error this time or simply nothing, like before?

Comment: I missed the second, but yes, just now I tried it. Right the same result.

Comment: Despite I found in docs `Caution: If you invoke an intent and there is no app available on the device that can handle the intent, your app will crash.` I get my log cat message and my app neither crash, nor shows ohter's app activity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out my mistake.

In the project there are two similar messages in two activities, so I thought that runs one, but that was another.

Thank you for your assistance!