# How to run "Start tracking" activity of an Endomondo mobile app

Tags: java, android

I'd like to create an app that starts tracking of endomondo. 
I do not want to use Tasker or some other trick, I'm learning Java for Android, although I'm a beginner,  and I'd just like to write such simple app.

So is it possible, to run the "Start tracking" action of endomondo mobile application on android? I cannot find such intent of this package.

If that's not possible, then maybe someone has another idea? There's no public API as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As much as the Endomondo part is concerned, I just managed to start it from the Tasker like app using:

```
package: com.endomondo.android
activity class: com.endomondo.android.EndoSplash
```

So following e.g.:
[How to start activity in another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application)

you could manage with something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(
    new ComponentName(
        "com.endomondo.android",
        "com.endomondo.android.EndoSplash")
    );
startActivity(intent);
```