# How to open particular activity of 3rd party application

Tags: android, android-intent

I know I can open Activity with `Intent` but I am trying to open particular Activity from my application.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.3rdPartyApplcation");
if (launchIntent != null) 
{
     startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Example:-
My application is A I have to open **Settings page** of Application B which is 3rd party application, I also know the activity name.

How to open this settings page via intent

Comment: solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210073/1872098 and third party app  activity must have exported = true in manifest

Comment: Most likely, that activity is not exported, and therefore you cannot start it.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent I also added android:exported="true"

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find out the package name of the app u want to launch using intent along with the activity name which u want to launch directly from your app.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.3rdPartyApplcation.packagename", "com.3rdPartyApplcation.packagename.SettingsActivity"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent I also added android:exported="true"

Comment: The activity which u launch must be  declared as android:exported="true" in manifest.xml. Otherwise u got the exception