# I use intent to start an another appliaction's activity class why i fail?

Tags: android

In frist appliaction ,i want use intent to lunach another application's activity class ,and this class is belong another application! them are not in same application. i dont have and not know second application's activity 's  action and other value in it's AndroidManifits.xml .

how i fix it? i remember this code could run a week ago ,now it can't...

help

these code could run before some days ago ,but now it can't, because second application had update?, but his class name,package name never changed!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ComponentName apk2Component1 =
                new ComponentName(the second appliaction's package name, the second appliaction's activity class name);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        mIntent.setComponent(apk2Component1);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
}
```

---

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="d"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.chinarainbow.tft/.mvp.ui.activity.TFTQRActivity } from ProcessRecord{8525c14 17370:com.dqj.tianfu/u0a802} (pid=17370, uid=10802) not exported from uid 10005
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6701)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:249)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:108)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=class name } from ProcessRecord{8525c14 17370:com.dqj.tianfu/u0a802} (pid=17370, uid=10802) not exported from uid 10005
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1954)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1900)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4536)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4494)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4855)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4823)
        at com.dqj.tianfu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7050)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6701) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:249) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783) 
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:108)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start activity in another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application)

Answer (score 0):

it's possible the app you're launching has disabled the `exported` flag, which controls whether other apps can launch it. You may want to set that flag to `true` in the app you're launching:

```
<service
    android:exported="true"
/>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#exported

Comment: thank your help,and it still crach 。i add " android:exported="true"" into the frist application,and still crash,same logcat . you meaning i add android:exported="true" into second applaiction ,but  second applaiction is others i dont have his source code