# Disable Application Icon While Clicking on Home Screen

Tags: android, icons, disable

I have installed the app programmatically through other application. Now if I click the application icon in home screen it should not open the app. App can be only able to open while clicking through the app I installed. Can Anyone hep on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the start activity looks like this in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LaunchActivity">    
    <intent-filter>    
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.categor.LAUNCHER" />    
    </intent-filter>    
</activity>
```

Now, if you remove the `<intent-filter>` part, it will not have an icon on the home screen.
Finally, you can follow this StackOverflow answer about how you can open your activity from another app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210073/1395437

Comment: If we remove the <intent-filter> could not run the application. It shows default activity not found.

Comment: You have to select an activity for that in your run configuration, since there is no way to launch it from the home screen.

Comment: if we select a activity in run configuration, It hides the icon. But while opening app from another application it does not open

Comment: Make sure it is exported.